# Browser not rendering anchor tag inspite of being part of Page source

Tags: html, tags, rendering

This is yet another confusing issue in HTML.  I've an anchor tag, which I build dynamically from server side using java.  The tag is viewable when I do view source, but it doesn't show up in the browser.  Even when I do inspect element, I don't see it.  My question why is the tag not being rendered inspite of being part of page source. Following is the tag:

```
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: Hidden by CSS? Removed by JavaScript? Overflowed by something else?  This is impossible to answer with the information provided.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've checked that as well.  There are no changes done to visibility. This tag is not manipulated by any other code.

Comment: Er just noticed that tag only has whitespace as its content so wont be visible anyway, does it appear if you put text inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add some sort of timeout in Java when creating `<a>` tag, just like timeout or delay in JavaScript. Based on information you provided, I cannot help you more.